# hibernate lists

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm currently trying to learn hibernate, and its going but I have hit a bit of a road bump here. Lists.

Basically, I am currently trying to extend the [Parent/Child example from the manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/example-parentchild.html)  so it uses a indexed list rather than a set.

I was guessing (since the manual really dont provide a lot of material on this) that i needed something like this:

```
    <list name="benefits" table="Child">
        <key column="ParentId"/>
            <list-index column="position"/>
        <one-to-many class="ChildClass"/>
    </list>
```

but its not working

> Initial SessionFactory creation
>   failed.org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read XML

I cant make this work, and I'm wondering what the correct way to go about this is? can anybody throw me a hint here? Do i place the SET element inside the LIST element in the mapping file?

Comment: any error to show? how do you know its not working?

Comment: "Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read XML" , the mapping file works fine when using a SET element instead of the above quoted list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read ["Indexed collections"](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#collections-indexed)? If you're learning Hibernate, you should be learning [the annotations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/), not XML mapping, unless there's a specific need for it.

The only strange thing I see about that mapping is that you don't declare a "table" on a one-to-many mapping. It's only for many-to-manys. That doesn't make the mapping unreadable, though. I think your problem is elsewhere.